# How to access VNC server running in an android phone in another computer?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, linux, vnc

I have installed Ubuntu in my Android phone and I can access its GUI in my phone by connecting a VNC viewer to `localhost:1`. The VNC server is running inside Android.

Is it possible to access this in a computer connected to the wifi hotspot of the phone?

I connected to computer to the phone's hotspot and tried to access `locahost:1` in Real VNC Viewer, but it says "The connection was refused by the remote computer".

Please note that I am **not** trying to access vnc server running in another computer in my phone but the opposite.

Comment: How are you running this VNC server _on_ Android?

Comment: Yes, I updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to **Setting** > **About Phone** and note down the ip address of your mobile phone.

Now connect to the Wifi hotspot of your mobile phone. In the VNC viewer, connect to the address `ip-address-of-mobile-phone:1`, to access the `localhost:1` of the mobile phone.